# Log Jenkins build results to central location

Tags: logging, jenkins

I'm trying to get my Jenkins master to log write a central log of build results from all its slaves. We'd like to enable this in one place (by adding a log handler or similar during initialization) instead of enabling it on a per-job basis. If possible it would be nice to write the results to a separate log file and if the output where structured in some way (eg. xml or json).

Is this possible? We have been looking for an existing logger to use but haven't been able to find one yet.

//Thomas

Comment: May I ask what you intend to achieve by centralizing the logging mechanism ??

Comment: The end result that we want to achieve is to be able to send all completed jobs as events to logstash without relying on users themselves to enable publishers in the individual jobs.